# Only allowing access to / and not /api/** in Spring Boot

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to figure out how to only allow access to my `index.html` page and its related resources. I have a a React application running along side a Spring Boot app.

This is what I have at the moment in my security configuration class:

```java
        http
            .csrf().disable();
        http
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/token/refresh/**").permitAll();
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/user/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER");
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/user/save/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN");
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/jobs/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER");
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/companies/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER");
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/company/save/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER");
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/contacts/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER");
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/contact/save/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER");
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/stock-items/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER");
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/stock-item/save/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER");
        http
            .addFilter(new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManagerBean()));
        http
            .addFilterBefore(new AuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

If I add `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();` before the `http.addFilter();` I'm able to see my React page in the browser no problem. However, when I then use Postman and access what should be a restricted resource without any login tokens, it's exposed. Which is not what I want at all.

How do I go about allowing access to my React page (should be found on `/index.html`) and its related resources, but prevent access to any other paths?

I know `/**` is the root path so any further requests down the line would be exposed automatically.

EDIT:-

I've changed this to the following:

```
http
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/token/refresh/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/user/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/user/save/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/jobs/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/companies/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/company/save/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/contacts/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/contact/save/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/stock-items/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/stock-item/save/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/index.html").permitAll()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManagerBean()))
                .addFilterBefore(new AuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

As requested and it's now exposing the secured endpoints (which is not what I want). So I could be doing it incorrectly.

EDIT 2:-

AuthenticationFilter

```
@Slf4j
public class AuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public AuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        log.info("Username is: {}", username);

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);

        return authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Map<String, String> tokens = Secret.generateTokenMap(authentication, request);
        response.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        new ObjectMapper().writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), tokens);
    }
```

EDIT 3:-

AuthorizationFilter

```
@Slf4j
public class AuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if(
                request.getServletPath().equals("/api/login") ||
                request.getServletPath().equals("/api/token/refresh")
        ) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            String authorisationHeader = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION);

            if(authorisationHeader != null && authorisationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                try {
                    String token = authorisationHeader.substring("Bearer ".length());

                    JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(Objects.requireNonNull(Secret.getSecret())).build();

                    DecodedJWT decodedJWT = verifier.verify(token);

                    String username = decodedJWT.getSubject();
                    String[] roles = decodedJWT.getClaim("roles").asArray(String.class);

                    Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
                    stream(roles).forEach(role -> authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role)));
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, authorities);

                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
                    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    log.error("Error logging in: {}", e.getMessage());
                    response.setHeader("error", e.getMessage());
                    response.setStatus(FORBIDDEN.value());

                    Map<String, String> error = new HashMap<>();
                    error.put("error_message", e.getMessage());
                    response.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
                    new ObjectMapper().writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), error);
                }
            } else {
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit 4:-

Here is the [Github repository](https://github.com/JamieRhys/hireout) of the project so far.

Comment: Why do you repeating `http.authorizeRequests()` every time? You could use method chaining, that is far more readable.

Comment: @dur would that look like ```http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/index.html").permitAll();```? If so, this does not work at all and I get a 403 error.

Comment: Is that line the reason: `response.setStatus(FORBIDDEN.value());`. I guess that you forget to excluded this URL with the others: `request.getServletPath().equals("/api/login") ||                request.getServletPath().equals("/api/token/refresh")`.

Comment: So adding it into that if statement ensures that I can see the correct thing... Except it exposes all of the secured end points again which is not what I want

Comment: you are aware that using JWTs as sessions is not a good choice, as your code looks like now you cant logout a user, and that spring security already has built in support for handling JWTs so your AuthorizationFilter is completely unnecassary, and its bad practice to write custom security handling here you can look at a project using the spring security JWT handling https://github.com/Tandolf/spring-security-jwt-demo